# Fitting a warehouse pricing tariff into MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, normalization

Creating the right database structure from a manual tariff

I have been assigned a rather challenging database design and thought someone may be able to give me a few pointers to help get going.  We currently have a warehouse goods in and goods out system and now we would like to use the data to calculate storage charges.
The database already holds the following: Goods date in, Goods date out, Consignment weight, Number of pieces, Dimensions, Description of goods, Storage container type (if applicable).  The data is held in MySQL which may not be suitable for the tariff structure below.

Here is the charging structure for Band 1,2,3,4. We have about 12 bands dependent on Customer size and importance.  All the other bands are derivatives of the following:

BAND 1
On arrival in our facility
€0.04 per kilo + €4.00 per consignment for general cargo
€0.07 per kilo for MAGAZINES – NO STORAGE CHARGE
STORAGE CHARGES AFTER 5 DAYS
€4.00 per intact pallet max size 120x100x160cm (Standard warehouse wooden pallet)
€6.50 per cubic metre on loose cargo or out of gauge cargo.
CARGO DELIVERED IN SPECIFIC CONTAINERS
20FT PALLET ONLY - €50.00
40FT PALLET ONLY - €20.00

BAND 2
0.04 per kilo no min charge
STORAGE CHARGES AFTER 6 DAYS
€2.50 per cubic metre
CONTAINERS
20FT PALLET ONLY - €50.00
40FT PALLET ONLY - €20.00

BAND 3
€0.03 per kilo + €3.00 per consignment up to 2000kg
€0.02 per kilo + €2.00 per consignment over 2000kg
STORAGE CHARGES AFTER 5 DAYS
€4.00 per pallet max size 120x100x160
€0.04 per kilo loose cargo

BAND 4
€5.00 per pallet 
STORAGE CHARGES AFTER 4 DAYS
€5.00 per pallet max size 120x100x160

My thoughts so far are to collect the charging band on arrival of the freight then try and fit the tariff into a table with some normalisation such as container type.

Anyone had experience of this type of manual to system conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the algorithm for computing the tariff is too messy to do in SQL.  So, let's approach your question from a different point of view.

1. Build the algorithm in your client language (Java/PHP/VB/...).
2. As you are doing step 1, think about what data is needed - perhaps a 2-column array of "days" and "Euros"?  Maybe something involving "kilos"?  Maybe there are multiple patterns -- days *and/or* kilos?
3. Build the table or tables necessary to store those arrays.
4. Decide how to indicate that kilos is irrelevant -- perhaps by leaving out any rows in the kilo table?  Or an extra column that gives size/weight?

My point is that the algorithm needs to drive the task; the database is merely a persistent store.

Here's another approach.  Instead of having columns for days, kilos, etc, just have a JSON string of whatever factors are needed.  In the client code, decode the JSON, then have suitable IF statements to act on kilos if present, ELSE ... etc.

Again, the database is just a persistent store; the client is driving the format by what is convenient to it.

In either implementation, there would be a column for the type of item involved, plus the `Band`.  The `SELECT` would have `ORDER BY Band`.  Note that there would be no concept of 12; any number *could* be implemented.

Performance?  Fetching all ~12 rows and stepping through them -- this should not be a performance problem.  If you had a thousand bands, you *might* notice a slight delay.